# Obtener un valor seleccionado correcto

Tags: php

Hola que tal soy un novato en programación mi duda es la siguiente... Lo que pasa esque quiero que al apretar el botón de "obtener texto" recupere el texto que se encuentra en la caja de texto... pero el error es que al presionar el segundo recupera el primero nadamas el codigo es el siguiente....

```
<html>

    <?php
include('con_rock.php');
$mysqli->real_query('SELECT *from evento');
$query=$mysqli->store_result();

    while($row=$query->fetch_assoc()){
        $id=$row['id_even'];
        echo '
        <input type="text" id="id_evento" value="'.$id.'">
        <input type="button" value="Obtener texto" onclick="capturar()">';

    }

    ?>

     <script>
     function capturar(){
         var porId=document.getElementById("id_evento").value;
         alert(porId);
     }

    </script>
</html>
```

Se los agradecería mucho

Comment: No puedes tener elementos con el mismo `id`.

Comment: en este caso como podria obtenerlos de acuerdo al seleccionado

Comment: Te recomiendo que uses jQuery

Comment: exactamente que te trae el id , es solo un numero?

Comment: dime como estas tratando de mostrar esa caja de texto

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que enviar el id del elemento como parámetro de la función.

```
<html>
    <?php
include('con_rock.php');
$mysqli->real_query('SELECT *from evento');
$query=$mysqli->store_result();

    while($row=$query->fetch_assoc()){
        $id=$row['id_even'];
        echo '
        <input type="text" id="id_'.$id.'" value="'.$id.'">
        <input type="button" value="Obtener texto" onclick="capturar('.$id.')">';
    }
    ?>
     <script>
     function capturar(id){
         var porId=document.getElementById("id_"+id).value;
         alert(porId);
     }

    </script>
</html>
```